# Writing a new jit

Tags: c++, assembly, jit

I'm interested in starting my own JIT project in C++. I'm not that unfamiliar with assembly, or compiler design etc etc. But, I am very unfamiliar with the resulting machine code format - like, what does a mov instruction actually look like when all is said and done and it's time to call that function pointer. So, what are the best resources for creating such a thing?

Edit: Right now, I'm only interested in x86 on Windows, stretching a tiny bit to 64bit Windows in the future.

Comment: Depends on what machine architecture you are running it on.

Comment: You want to write a JIT for C++?

Comment: @Martin: It's written *in* C++. I have some ideas about the language that I'm going to JIT, but it's more of a secondary concern.

Comment: What's the point of writing a JIT if you don't know the target architecture (machine code) well?

Comment: @J-16: Writing a JIT is about the code I'm JITing, not the machine code I'm JITing into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to have a look at the processor manuals for the architecture you are interested in. Those manuals describe the opcode encoding. For x86 processors, the manuals can be downloaded from [this page](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).

Comment: Oh man, that stuff is dry. I thought that things like near/far pointers and segment registers were deprecated? I scrolled down to the ADD instruction, and holy hell, that's unreadable.

Comment: @ruslik: Aren't those the same as the Intel x64 opcodes? You know, since x64 code executes on both CPUs? Also, I think I may have just forgotten to read the right part of the manual that explained how to read the other part.

Comment: @DeadMG: Wait until you see how they encode each instruction. That's heaps of fun (read: almost no discernible structure). It's the stuff of nightmares.

Answer (score 5):

Starting your project on top of LLVM might shield you from the platform details.

http://llvm.org/

LLVM is used by several dynamic language JIT compilers.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) is a multi-architecture (x86, SPARC, PPC) library for generating code within another program.  You'll need to understand general assembly language concepts, but not at a very deep level.  You won't have to write anything architecture-specific at all.  The down side to lightning (at least last time I used it) is that the interface presented is the intersection of the features available on the supported targets:  The small register set of x86, a RISC instruction set like SPARC, and so on.  The single-pass code generation is easy to use but has its own quirks, like you can't relocate your output buffer (because of address references) so if you run out of space you generally have to start over.  The good thing is that you will probably get a working example going very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of NASM come with a fairly concise opcode reference that has x86 instruction encodings. (Looks like there's no 64-bit info, though.) I found this one using google:

http://alien.dowling.edu/~rohit/nasmdocb.html

The official manuals say basically the same thing (and a lot more besides), but not quite so conveniently.